# How to populate ListBox with Display and Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I am trying to populate my ListBox control in my WebForm from a SQL query. I want the DisplayMember and ValueMember to be the same. This is what I have so far:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();

    string strQuery = "SELECT Client from filtername";
    SqlDataAdapter sdaClient = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
    DataSet dsClient = new DataSet();
    sdaClient.Fill(dsClient, "filtername");
    DataTable dtClient = dsClient.Tables[0];
    DataRow drTemp = null;

    foreach (DataRow drTempRow in dtClient.Rows)
    {
        drTemp = drTempRow;
        lbEnt.Items.Add(drTemp["Client"]);
    }
}
```

`lbEnt` is the ID of my ListBox. With the above code, I am getting the following error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection.Add' has some invalid
>   arguments.

How do I modify the code to populate the listbox with the return from the query?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection.Add(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it expects a `string`

Comment: or a `ListItem`. Is `drTemp["Client"]` == to null?

Comment: yes @mickey you are right

Comment: Either `lbEnt.Items.Add(drTemp["Client"].ToString());` or add it as a ListItem as @mickey suggests.

Comment: `.toString()` solved it for me.

Comment: Any particular reason you assign another variable in the foreach - "drTemp = drTempRow"? Seems unnecessary.

Comment: No particular reason. You are right and I will remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ListItem, this way you can provide a Text and a Value string:

```
lbEnt.Items.Add(new ListItem(drTemp["Client"].ToString(),drTemp["Client"].ToString()));
```

Comment: I am wondering if you can also assist me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162698/how-to-cascade-dropdowns-from-left-to-right-and-right-to-left-in-a-sharepoint-we   Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
         drTemp["Client"].ToString()
```

You may need to convert the value to String before adding it.

Comment: That worked fine. Thank you. It shows up in the ListBox but will it also give the `Value` the same display?